# Prevent users from changing amount charged on payment page

Tags: javascript, php, html, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate payment gateway on my website.  There are three courses each having different prices. I am passing the value of the amount and package to `form.php` and i have made the input fields to readonly but the user can still change the amount in inspect element and make it 0 and pass on the value and get the course for free. How can i stop user from changing the value? or is there any other way to pass the value? or encrypt it and then decrypt it again?

here is my code `index.php`

```
<div id="outer">
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Rs. 9,900/-</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>2-Days Classroom Training</li>
                <li>E-Learning Course</li>
            </ul>
            <form action="form.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9900" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="hidden" name="package" value="basic" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="submit" name="BUY NOW" value="BUY NOW">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Rs. 11,900/-</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>4-Days Classroom Training</li>
                <li>E-Learning Course</li>
            </ul>
            <form action="form.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="11900" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="hidden" name="package" value="standard" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="submit" name="BUY NOW" value="BUY NOW">
            </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Rs. 14,900/-</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>4-Days Classroom Training</li>
                <li>E-Learning Course</li>
                <li>5 Hours Personal Session With The Trainer</li>
            </ul>
            <form action="form.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="14900" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="hidden" name="package" value="pro" readonly="readonly">
                <input type="submit" name="BUY NOW" value="BUY NOW">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`form.php`

```
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['amount']) && isset($_POST['package'])) {
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            $package = $_POST['package'];
        }
    ?>

<div>
<table>
    <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
    <tr><td>txnid</td><td><input type="text" name="txnid" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>firstname</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Package</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $package; ?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://localhost/payment/success.php" size="64" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://localhost/payment/failure.php" size="64" readonly="readonly" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

`form_process.php`

```
<script>
    function submitForm() {
      var postForm = document.forms.postForm;
      postForm.submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['firstname'])){header("location: form.php");}
// Change the Merchant key here as provided by Payumoney
$MERCHANT_KEY = "*******";

// Change the Merchant Salt as provided by Payumoney
$SALT = "********";


    $firstname =$_POST['firstname'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $phone =$_POST['phone'];
    $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
    $service_provider =$_POST['service_provider'];
    $amount =$_POST['amount'];
    $txnid =$_POST['txnid'];
    $productinfo =$_POST['productinfo'];
    $surl =$_POST['surl'];
    $furl =$_POST['furl'];
    

    //$ =$_POST[''];

    $hashseq=$MERCHANT_KEY.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$amount.'|'.$productinfo.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$email.'|||||||||||'.$SALT;
    $hash =strtolower(hash("sha512", $hashseq)); 
    
?>

<body onload="submitForm();">

<div>
<h2>Payment Gateway Testing Sample</h2>
<table>
<tr><td>Transaction Id</td><td><strong><?php echo $_POST['txnid']; ?></strong></td><td>Amount: </td><td><strong>Rs. <?php echo $_POST['amount']; ?></strong></td>
</table>
<div >
<p>In this page we will genrate hash and send it to payumoney.</p>
<br>
<p>Please be patient. this process might take some time,<br />please do not hit refresh or browser back button or close this window</p>
</div>
</div>

<div>
    <form name="postForm" action="https://sandboxsecure.payu.in/_payment" method="POST" >
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash;  ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $_POST['txnid'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_POST['amount'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo $_POST['productinfo'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" />
        <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="<?php echo $_POST['surl'];  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="<?php echo $_POST['furl'];  ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

`success.php`

```
<body>
    <script>var time = 5;
setInterval(function() {
  var seconds = time % 60;
  var minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
  if (seconds.toString().length == 1) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes.toString().length == 1) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  time--;
  if (time == 0) {
    window.location.href = "index.php";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

    <div>
        <h2>Payment Success</h2>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['status'])){
                if($_POST['status']=="success"){
                    echo "<p>Payment Done Successfully.<br>Details Are Below.</p>";
                    echo "<p>Txn Id: ".$_POST['txnid']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>Name: ".$_POST['firstname']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>Email: ".$_POST['email']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>Amount: ".$_POST['amount']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>Phone No: ".$_POST['phone']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>Product Info: ".$_POST['productinfo']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>encryptedPaymentId: ".$_POST['encryptedPaymentId']."</p>";
                }
            }

            ?>
    </div>
    <div>Redirecting to home page in <span id="time"></span></div>
```

Comment: certainly don't put amount on the front end, make your calculations in backend and send it. or probably put that in a table somewhere, fetch the base price, then finally send it

Comment: make your calculations in php and use CURL. All will be done on server side.

Comment: i'd suggest though don't roll up your own, too many things to make mistakes, and just download a tested ecommerce framework

Comment: You can display the amount as text for user info. and after submit the form get the fixed amount like -  $amount = "XXXX";
            $package = "XXXX";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never let the user send the price. Each course has an ID. Let's assume this:

- course 1, has ID = 1, price = 499, name = 2-Days Classroom Training
- course 2, has ID = 2, price = 999, name = 4-Days Classroom Training

On your payment page, inside `<forms>` send only `course_id = X`.

On the PHP script which receives the request you know that `course_id = X` has `price = Y`... This is the price you will charge.

```
// index.php
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="1" readonly="readonly">
    <label>
        2-days learning course
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="BUY NOW" value="BUY NOW">
</form>


//form.php
if (isset($_POST['course_id']){
   if ($_POST['course_id'] == 1){
       $amount = 499;
   }
} else {
    echo 'invalid request'; exit();
}
```

Comment: how do i pass this value from `form.php` `<tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Package</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $package; ?>"/></td></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

U can do one thing to avoid the trap is that just make a session variable for the amount value and then fetch the session variable in the next page and then send the session variable for the amount element(mandatory) along with the others field which are encrypted/decrypted by the payment gateway.

Comment: Please provide example code to support your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Check the value of the field, if its zero, just kill the execution of the code, send the user back to the form and print a warning...

Or you could use JavaScript to validate the amount onClick and double check after submission.

***It's a jungle out there!!!***